# Hypernym for anything you would write on?

Tags: hypernyms

I know the term "writing utensil", "writing implement", or "writing instrument" can be used to encompass anything you would write with such as pen, pencil, stylus, etc. but I am looking for it's counterpart that encompasses all things you might write on such as paper, papyrus, notebook, clay tablet, etc.

To clarify, I am looking for a word that encompasses the whole thing you write on or in so "writing surface" does not quite fit.  For example, the writing surface of a notebook is just the page you write on, not the whole notebook, and the writing surface of a an iPad is just the screen, not the whole iPad.

Comment: Writing surface?

Comment: @nnnnnn Not a bad thought, but I am looking for a word that encompasses the whole thing.

Comment: Perhaps medium—a tablet, paper, a chalk board, the wall of a cave, a digital medium

Comment: Why exactly do you reject *writing surface*? Is it just because it sounds inelegant? Given that the need for this hypernym does not arise very often, there may not be anything more elegant.

Comment: **writing instrument and kitchen utensil**, please.

Comment: @Lambie Writing instrument, writing implement, & writing utensil are all correct terms, though some regions may consider one term more preferred than another. For example, British English considers utensil to exclusively be a kitchen or domestic tool, but American English is a different. The Merriam Webster dictionary definition #2 is "a useful tool or implement" and specifically uses "Writing utensil" as the example given of this non-kitchen use of the word.  But thanks for raising this concern.   I'll go ahead and revise the question to better account for different English dialects.

Comment: Portable writing surface

Comment: Believe me, writing utensil is not used by anyone I know in the States regardless of Merriam Webster. It is not actually in the definition and that sample sentence is weird.

Comment: @Lambie Might be more regional then.  I wanted to double check my assumptions; so, last night I asked a few people I know to complete the sentence "Pens and pencils are examples of a writing ___." and all 5 people answered "utensil"... not exactly a publication worthy sample size, but I think it proves the point that at least it belongs to an established dialect, and not just some weird thing that only I say.

Comment: Quick internet search also shows tons of uses of this phrase by fairly reputable websites. https://study.com/academy/lesson/writing-utensils-history-list-types.html , https://grammarcheckerpro.com/writing-utensils-list/ , https://whenyouwrite.com/writing-utensils/ , https://www.wordhippo.com/what-is/another-word-for/writing_utensil.html , etc.

Comment: @Nosajimiki When I googled writing **utensil**, up popped Wikipedia with writing implement or instrument. The article does not mention utensil at all. I have never heard writing utensil and I hang out with people ranging from elites to "trailer" trash in the US NE.

Comment: @Lambie That is because Wikipedia redirects "writing utensil" to "writing implement" to reduce redundant articles.  When Wikipedia does this, it means they have multiple articles and merge them into whatever article happens to be most complete, not necessarily the most widely used term.  The original page https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Writing_utensil&oldid=1047888 was lacking content so it was merged into the writing implement page as a synonym.

Comment: But the articles for Stylus and Pen both use the term "writing utensil" showing the actual commonness of the term, even by Wikipedia users.  This bias towards Writing Implement on Google comes from the algorythmn using Wikipedia to canonically group synonyms.  But other search engines like Bing don't have this bias.  So, if you search on Bing you get 278,000 results for writing utensil which is more than the 185,000 results you get for writing implement which is what Wikipedia redirects you to.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All of the items you describe are **writing materials**. The Oxford English Dictionary includes a collocation for this under "[writing, n.](https://oed.com/view/Entry/230775)":

> d. In sense ‘used or designed for writing upon’, as **writing cloth, writing material, writing slate, writing surface**. Also writing-book n., writing-paper n.
>   ...
>
> > 1875   E. H. Knight Pract. Dict. Mech. 2477/2   Table, a tablet..[or] **writing-surface**.
> >
> > 1888   J. W. Burgon Lives Twelve Good Men II. v. 36   To get out his **writing materials**, and to scribble.

The hypernym can refer to either surfaces or utensils, depending on context. The OED examples are all from the 19th century, so I looked for a few more recent examples.

1. *[Ancient Writing Materials](https://www.lib.umich.edu/papyrology-collection/ancient-writing-materials)*, a University of Michigan website that documents materials used by ancient people for writing: "Ancient writers wrote on a variety of other materials besides papyrus, including **pottery, animal hides, wood, and even ancient paper**."
2. A [Materials Research Society](https://www.mrs.org/) lesson, "[Module 10 Writing Materials](https://www.mrs.org/docs/default-source/programs-and-outreach/imos-course/module-10/module-10-outline-of-instruction-for-faculty---writing-materials-updated65dacf8cc9d76e4e916fff0000759bd3.pdf?sfvrsn=530da111_6)," includes this list of examples: "We will identify the properties of different **writing materials, including stone, papyrus, parchment, and paper**, and discusses the implications of the transition from manual to mechanical and digital printing. "
3. A [National Association for the Education of Young Children](https://www.naeyc.org/) guide, "[Promoting Preschoolers’ Emergent Writing](https://www.naeyc.org/resources/pubs/yc/nov2017/emergent-writing)," gives this advice: "Strategically place **writing materials**, such as sticky notes, small chalkboards, whiteboards, envelopes, clipboards, journals, stencils, golf pencils, markers, and various types, sizes, and colors of paper throughout the classroom."

Answer (score 1):

***[medium](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/medium)*** (Lexico/Oxford)

> **4** The material or form used by an artist, composer, or writer.

Usage, however, is mostly in the context of art than writing.

Xanne already noted this term in their comment. *Writing surface* as suggested by nnnnnn works, too, and is more common.

Comment: As the quoted definition itself makes clear, this sense of *medium* applies to the material, generally, used by an artist, not specifically the surfaces that pigments are applied to, which is what the OP is asking about. In fact, the word is typically applied only to the most noticeable material, and that is usually not the surface: for example, if an artist paints by applying oil paint to canvass, we are more likely to say that his medium is oil, than that it is canvass.

Comment: @jsw29 Writer, writing -- note the context -- it's nothing much about art.

Comment: Thanks for the generous down vote, too.

Comment: The OP's question may have been 'nothing much about art', but the answer is, in its own words, about a term that is used 'mostly in the context of art [rather] than writing'. In any event, the answer is about 'materials', generally, while the OP is looking for a specific term for the writing surface, as distinct from the other materials involved (i.e. the materials that are applied to the surface, such as ink).

Answer (score 1):

How about just "surface"? Here are some others that might work:
-stage 
-field 
-backdrop 
-canvas

Canvas (and any of the rest, really) can be used as a metonym for anything one can paint/draw/write on. Take the quote by Thoreau: 
"This world is but a canvas to our imagination."